# Unable to set DataContext through XAML, but the same can be set through Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

Datacontext does not work when I declare it in XAML. But the same works if set in Code.

Detailed Analysis.

My XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="SimpleDatabindingwithclass.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="windo">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=windo,Path=objectOfStudent}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Margin="25" Height="25" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=StudentName}"></TextBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Corresponding code.

```
    namespace SimpleDatabindingwithclass
    {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
         public MainWindow()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
              Student objectOfStudent = new Student();
              objectOfStudent.StudentName = "John diley";
              objectOfStudent.Address = "20, North Travilia, Washington DC.";
              //not setting datacontext here since i set that in xaml
         }
         public class Student
         {
             private string studentname;
             private string address;

             public string Address
             {
                 get { return address; }
                 set { address = value; }
        }
        public string StudentName
        {
            get{return studentname;}
            set{studentname = value;}
        }
    }
}
```

}

But, the same when I use this XAML & set datacontext through code, it works!

ie, When I put something like

```
     this.DataContext = objectOfStudent;
```

in MainWindow(), the application Works! 
What do u think the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding only works with public properties, you can't bind to some local variable. Make `objectOfStudent` as public property of your `MainWindow`.

Edit:

```
public Student objectOfStudent { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    objectOfStudent = new Student();
    objectOfStudent.StudentName = "John diley";
    objectOfStudent.Address = "20, North Travilia, Washington DC.";
    //not setting datacontext here since i set that in xaml
 }
```

Edit:

Also you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface in the `MainWindow` and `Student` classes and raise `PropertyChanged` when you set the properties. That is the right way, the binding will be updated everytime you change the properties. Or a simple way: create `objectOfStudent` before calling `InitializeComponent`.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    objectOfStudent = new Student();
    objectOfStudent.StudentName = "John diley";
    objectOfStudent.Address = "20, North Travilia, Washington DC.";
    InitializeComponent();
    //not setting datacontext here since i set that in xaml
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Zabasky. I understand that the objectofStudent is something related to class Student and is a local variable. Now, how do I make it a property of MainWindow ? Simply, how to add a property and refer it to the Student instance ?

Comment: that still didn work Zabavsky! Still both textfields are empty!
After adding public Student objectOfStudent { get; set; }
I used 
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=windo,Path=objectOfStudent}">
in the above XAML Code.

Comment: Zabavsky @thanks for the input. still didn get that right. Anyways, the problem definition was clear.

Comment: @Madhuresh to get the right way just read more about `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and what it is used for.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to use a **local variable** named `objectOfStudent` via XAML - this has no meaning in the context of XAML. XAML only accepts fields and properties, not local variables.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use an object of a class in XAML? How do I port this to the XAML instead of putting it n code? sorry, If this sounds silly but this is kind of freaking out me!

Comment: You can add a property named "Student' to your Window class which returns a Student insatnce and then use it instead of 'objectOfStudent'